# Eevee Render artifacts

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, artifacts

When I render out animation in eevee, I get these weird black artifacts in my pngs from sequence.

When I render just by single frames, everything is fine. But when I render as an animation. I get these artifacts in every frame.

What can possibly cause the artifacts?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*fixed*

Unticking "Refraction" box in render settings -> screen space reflections solver the issue.